# why it show 777 when first time

Tags: c, linux

this is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>


void foo(void)
{
    int i;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    i = 777;
}

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    //printf("hello\n");
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

it show :

```
-1079087064
777
```

but if you remove the `//` in the code , it will be show :

```
134513817
hello
13541364
```

so why it show 777 when first time ,

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  You are printing the value of an uninitialized variable.  The number could be based on whatever was previously in the memory location of that variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be 777 both times do this:

```
void foo(void)
{
    int i = 777;
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Let me also explain why it is uninitialized something gives this undefined behavior. When you make a variable it allocates some memory for the variable. This memory could already have some values on it from other programs previously using that (or those) memory blocks. These value are then stored on the variable until you make it something else such as assigning it with the = operator.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it showed 777 the first time (without the printf) because of how your c compiler works and converts the c to assembly using a stack based memory model. Check wikipedia about assembly language and stacks for more information.

In your first test, you entered the function foo, it 'created' (probably by just moving the stack pointer) the space on the stack for the local variable i, printed it's garbage value (-1079087064) then set that memory to 777. It then returned to main and called foo again. This call behaves exactly the same as the first, it 'creates' it's room for i in the same place as the previous call, and prints whatever value is there. Since that memory was previously set to 777 that is what was printed. The two foo calls would compile to something like this:

```
call foo
call foo
```

In your second example there is a call to printf between the calls to foo.

```
call foo
; code to set up call to printf, probably involving stack
call printf ; most definitely changing the stack
; clean up also probably changes the stack
call foo
```

Thus the assignment of the variable i in stack memory was altered by the many assignments involved in calling printf. The subsequent call to foo just prints out a new garbage value, presumably at the same memory location as before.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is not initialized to anything but asking to print what it has. So, it can print anything ( garbage values ) which is what the *undefined behavior*.